# Is In app purchase server verificarion mandatory?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, cocos2d-x

I’m making a game using Cocos2dx and I tried LiveOps of sdkbox to verify the app purchase but doesn’t work. I always get a message:
IAP :Server validation: not authenticated

i tried multiple things to fix this but the only way to avoid it is  setting the userSideVerification to true. With this configuration i get in the console all the purchase information including the receipt but i don’t make any verification by my side.

The thing is that Apple already aprove the game to publish it with no verification by me so, will i have problems to get the revenue of the purchases or this is only a thing to avoid piracy?

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

You are not required by apple to verify you receipt from a server. It is mainly to help avoid piracy. You will receive your percentage from all revenue apple collects, which you can check in from your itunes connect account.

Comment: Thanks!!!! really appreciate. For your entertainment check out the trailer of thegame;) 
https://vimeo.com/306597858